# Rails MVC - How to pass a randomly generated array to the next page with the same elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm creating a TextTwist like game.

```
def initialize
  super
  @letters = ('a'..'z').to_a.sample(10)
end

def game
  # @letters = ('a'..'z').to_a.sample(10)
end
  
def results
  #How to display letters
end
```

So in my game page, I display an array of random letters which I declared in the game method of my controller. The problem is, in my results page, where I return back the same array of random letters and reveal if user was able to create a word from the random letters. I need to display those same array of random letters. I tried declaring them in initialize, but when I called them on my results page it displayed a different set of random letters.

In my HTML page, I use `<%=letters>` to display the array. And then a form for them to type the word. When they submit, user goes to the results page. Is there a way for me to pass `<%=letters>` to the next page and be displayed?

Comment: You can store your values in the session, store them in a temporary table, or pass them to another controller or controller action as an instance variable. However, you might be better off treating this generator as a helper rather than a controller method. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem with rails session feature. You can store the letters that generated in game action to the session and then when the user submit the form then you can get that previously generated letter array from session. Here is the code example for this:

```rb
def game
  @letters = ('a'..'z').to_a.sample(10)
  session[:letters] = @letters
end

def result
  @letters = session[:letters]
end
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I saw suggestions online to use the form to pass information on the next page, but I'll stick to this until I find the form way.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add a [`hidden_field_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag) to your form and store the serialized value of `@letters` in that field.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :letters, @letters.join(',') %>
```

The value of that field will then be passed to the controller again when the form is submitted. In the controller, you can then read the letters from the params:

```
@letters = params[:letters].split(',')
```

Another option might be making the `Game` a `ActiveRecord` model and storing the random letters for a specific game in the database.